# How to render image on react client side send from express js

Tags: reactjs, express, blob

I want to display the image in page send from server, but what I am receiving on client side are thousands of strange characters (possibly blob). I'm using react on client side. I am sending data using `res.sendfile()` method. If there's any other strategy, then please share.

Comment: If you console.log img source you'll see a blob or lots of characters. You need to use an img tag and set the source as that data.

Comment: @Arcanus The data I'm getting are thousands of characters, with some characters not showing clear on screen. Also, in the console, its size is also mentioned, which is 580kb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you received multiple charters then it is base64.
you can render images with base64.

```
render(){
    {this.state.image ? <img src={`data:image/png;base64,${this.state.image}`}/>: ''}
}
```

if the image response is not base64 then you need to convert blob to base64.

Comment: I have found this answer very helpful, serves as a base for solving my error. I am receiving data in blob, and I'm trying to convert it to Base64 in client side using Javascript inbuilt functionality(FileReader and other stuff), but the basee64Url I'm getting is not accurate. So, I decided to do this conversion in server side using image-to-base64 package, sending the base64url to client and finally got success.